# User interaction in mobile app

Tags: mobile, heatmap, user-interaction

I am working on a mobile app and wanted to know if there is any plugin which traces the user interaction within the app. For ex. if user has clicked on any particular tab or navigated to any specific section of the app. I know crazy egg does this for web apps. I am looking something for mobile apps.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are many analytic libraries available to track events, some of them are Flurry, GoogleAnalytics, Mixpanel. You can try using any of them according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Sanjana! I will check Flurry and Mixpanel.